# How to draw gpx file in google maps

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-api, gpx

I implemented an application where I can store all the way points of the user while moving in a gpx file. I want to draw the route in google maps. I can easily get the longitude and the latitude information by parsing the xml file but I have no clue on how can I draw the path on the map. A sample code will be very appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            ArrayList<LatLng> points = null;
            PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = null;

            // traversing through routes
            for (int i = 0; i < routes.size(); i++) {
                points = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
                polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
                List<HashMap<String, String>> path = routes.get(i);

                for (int j = 0; j < path.size(); j++) {
                    HashMap<String, String> point = path.get(j);

                    double lat = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lat"));
                    double lng = Double.parseDouble(point.get("lng"));
                    LatLng position = new LatLng(lat, lng);

                    points.add(position);
                }

                polyLineOptions.addAll(points);
                polyLineOptions.width(2);
                polyLineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
            }
            //add the polyline in google map
            googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however can you give some explanation 'cause i don't understand the LatLng type that you are using. Thanks in advance

Comment: double latitude = 12.2432324; double longitude=12.53452342;LatLng location = new LatLng(latitude, longitude); This will be used to create current Location based on the current latitude and longitude